# Post and Get parameters in Alamofire request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I got one issue in my project:
Here is my url

> www.someapi.com/product/filter?range[column]=price&range[value][lte]=7000&range[value][gte]=1000&offset=10&limit=10&lang=en

As you see there is `GET` method paramaters

But I have use `POST` method, so the post body is

```
{"category_id":4017,"filter":[{"filter_id":"214","value_ids":["7632","6433"]}],"type":"2"}
```

So is it possible to combine get and post parameters in Alamofire? I was looking for answer in their github, but there is no any result.

Comment: When you send the POST request to server, you can also get the url parameters there. So you should just build the request.url with the parameters.

Comment: You can. btw, it's not Alamofire related, it's basic workings of a [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)-based api

Comment: Also, query-string parameters in the URL are not specific to `GET`. The actual question (to yourself) is whether that API allows `POST`. If it doesn't then you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can mix query string parameters with a `POST` body.

Also, duly note that query parameters aren't `GET` specific. As long as your API handles it, it will work.

This is not an Alamofire issue but rather has to do with your API design

- If an API **does not** support the `POST` method then you **can't** send a payload.
- If an API **does not** handle query string parameters, they **won't** work.

Basically your API should be designed to handle query string parameters and support the `POST` method in order for both to work.

---

Usage Example:

```
    let strURL = "www.someapi.com/product/filter?range[column]=price&range[value][lte]=7000&range[value][gte]=1000&offset=10&limit=10&lang=en"

    let payload: [String:Any] = ["category_id":4017,
                                 "filter":[["filter_id":"214",
                                            "value_ids":["7632",
                                                         "6433"]]],
                                 "type":"2"]

    Alamofire.request(strURL,
                      method: .post,
                      parameters: payload,
                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                      headers: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you! I had an idea to use this way, but the problem is link can be dynamic, for example, maybe there would not be range parameter or other. So I'm thinking about, to make some string for get parameters, and append parameters to this string

Comment: @RufatAbdul-zade Yeah, sure. You can string interpolate your url as much as you want, as long as your API will take it.